# what are some good underlaying hover colors for a dropdown menu on top of a black background

Tags: gui-design, navigation, color, hyperlinks, color-scheme

At the moment, I have a dropdown trigger within the navbar of my website. I want it to have a little bit of "niceness" to it whenever a user hovers of it (to indicate that the element is indeed clickable).

This is what I have so far (when the use hovers over the element):

[image: Hover over element]

Navbar: `#151515`
Hover: `#7b7b7b` 
Text: `#e6e6e6`
Profile Picture (Background): `#c0c0c0`

At the moment, I feel like the dark grey is a bit **too intense** (and it kind of overpowers the overlaying elements). And due to the way Chrome renders these colors (and the text), and it looks disgusting, in my opinion.

The main color for the website is `#730aa2` (dark ish purple), so I tried fading in between a darker version of that & a lighter version, but none of them worked.

Would anyone have any color codes (HEX or RBG) that you think would suit as an underlaying hover color?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since It is a website you have mentioned, you can place your sign in button on the far right side of your navbar.

You have also decided on your primary color, so using grey color on your sign in button/drop-down hover surprises me considering that it is an important CTA in your website.

I would suggest go with your primary color and use it on sign in CTA not only on hover but as default color something like this.

[image]

hope this helps.

Comment: Would you mind tell me where you found that user icon? :)

Comment: glad I could help :) user icon you can find in flaticon.com

Comment: Also don't forget touch devices can't hover!

Comment: @Martyn yeah, it's going to be a click-to-activate dropdown menu :-)

Comment: I can't manage to find the icon on flaticon.com.. would you happen to have a link to it? @prazor9

Comment: you can find it in here [usericon]( http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/black-male-user-symbol_44948#term=user icon&page=1&position=14)